# Pandas standard deviation on one column for subset of rows

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, standard-deviation

I'm new to working with Python and Pandas. Currently I'm attempting to create a report that extracts data from an SQL database and using that data in a pandas dataframe. In each row is a server name and date of sample and then sample data per column following that.

I have been able to filter by the hostname using
    df[df['hostname'] == uniquehost]
df being a variable for the dataframe and uniquehost being a variable for each unique host name.

What I am trying to do next is to obtain the stdev of the other columns although I haven't been capable of figuring this part out. I attempted to use
    df[df['hostname'] == uniquehost].std()

However, this wasn't correct.

Can anyone point me in the appropriate direction to get this figure out? I suspect I'm barking up the wrong tree and there's likely a very easy way to handle this that I haven't encountered yet.

```
Hostname | Sample Date | CPU Peak | Memory Peak 
server1 | 08/08/17 | 67.32 | 34.83 
server1 | 08/09/17 | 34 | 62
```

Comment: You'll need to start by showing us some data and desired output. Why is that not correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at my work laptop. Let me try to give an example of the data structure

The columns are as follows

`Hostname | Sample Date  | CPU Peak | Memory Peak
server1     |   08/08/17    |    67.32    |    34.83
server1     |   08/09/17    |    34         |    62`
This is the type of data for various servers

Comment: And what do you want to do a std on?

Comment: Also, do you want to find the std for each unique host?

Comment: I want the standard deviation for CPU peak and Mem Peak individually. I'm trying to get the stdev for each server's cpu and memory readings.

Comment: So in this case filtering the dataframe by server1 and then calculating the stdev for cpu peak, then calculating the stdev for memory peak so that I know the standard deviation for each metric and for each server.

Comment: Understood. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you'll want to first do `df.groupby` on `Hostname` and *then* find the standard deviation. Something like this:

```
In [118]: df.groupby('Hostname')[['CPU Peak', 'Memory Peak']].std()
Out[118]: 
           CPU Peak  Memory Peak
Hostname                        
server1   23.560798    19.212091
```

Comment: awesome thanks. I'll give this a try and get back to you.